# Javascript basic text only loading indicator

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I would like to use a basic, text only, loading indicator. So instead of using an image, I'd like to just show a text:

```
Loading ...
```

While some AJAX request is taking place. I would like this text to be changing like this:

```
Loading ...
```

Then:

```
Loading ..
```

Then:

```
Loading .
```

Then:

```
Loading ..
```

Then:

```
Loading ...
```

And so on. Any ideas? I can use jquery for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do something like this (adapt to your needs):

```
<span>loading</span>
<span class="dots"></span>
```

jQuery

```
function animateIt() {

 var text = '...';
 jQuery({count:0}).animate({count:text.length}, {
     duration: 2000,
     step: function() {
         $(".dots").text( text.substring(0, Math.round(this.count)) );
     },
     complete: function() {
         animateIt();
     }
  });
}

animateIt();
```

Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/uZkzX/